# Could not load file or assembly or one of its depencencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#-2.0

I am working to program (that was written by other people), this program is written in C#, using Visual Studio 2010. Almost everything was fine (except some logical problems) until i tried to rum my program in Release mode instead of Debug mode. This program downloads testing modules (PingTest.dll) and runs in when computer is Idle. Debug version stores all files in running folder while Release version "installs" into c:\Users\Macke\AppData\Local\NetMon\ and re-runs from there (all files needed to run are also storred there). So when i run NetMon.exe it crashes. I've added some try/catch and found an error:

Could not load file or assembly 'CountDow_Idle, version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its depencencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The part of the code that causes it: 
    AppDomain aDom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestingDomain");
                Assembly testAsm = null;

```
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(TMP_MOD_NAME, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);

                    testAsm = aDom.Load(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            INetMonTest iTest = null;
            foreach (Type type in testAsm.GetExportedTypes())
            {
                if (type.BaseType.FullName == "CountDown_Idle.INetMonTest")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        iTest = (INetMonTest)aDom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(TMP_MOD_NAME).FullName, type.FullName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("AppDomain creation failed:\n\n" + ex.Message);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I've allready looked for correct versions (in AssemblyInfo.cs file)

So maby anyone could help me. 
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found! Check names of your project files.

Debug file name is CountDown_Idle.exe, while release file name is NetMon.exe (it is renamed in auto installation). So i tried to run debug version from any place of my computer, it workd but if i changed it into NetMon.exe (instead of CountDown_Idle.exe) it didn't worked.. Now installer keeps the original file name and everything runs great. The thing is that program must be named NetMon.exe and i can't change it (even in program code) that it would work...